# Enum initialization using another enum

Tags: c, enums

I have to enums defined in two different .h files. (main.h and page1.h)

```
// MAIN.h
#define LAST_ENUM_FROM_PAGE_H (LastEnumPage1H) // no error HERE.

#include "page1.h"
typedef enum MAIN_H {
    FirstEnumMainH = LastEnumPage1H// get error HERE, undefined LastEnumPage1H
}MAIN_H;

// page1.h
#include "Main.h"
typedef enum PAGE1_H{
    LastEnumPage1H
}PAGE1_H;
```

My purpose is to have the last enum defined in pag1.h to be the first enum in main.h.
Unfortunately, I always get an error on main.h that the enum from page1.h is undefined.
But, If I create some #define using the main.h enum it works perfectly. 
Tried to #include page1.h in main.h also with no success.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you think that this might be because you haven't terminated the statements inside the curly braces by a semicolon?

Comment: @ParamSiddharth Enum lists do not use semicolons.

Comment: @kaylum I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: `main.h` does `#include "page1.h"` and `page1.h` does `#include "main.h"`. Think about it.